# What to do when attacking with GoVaHo and defending castle has air troops?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I recently entered TH 10. I find [GoVaHo attack strategy](https://www.allclash.com/govaho-3-star-attacking-strategy/) can be very hit and miss. Usually I have 4 wallbreakers, 8 wizards, 2 golem (1 in cc), 11 valkyries, 14 hogs, Barbarian King and Archer Queen.

What happens if there are air troops in the defending clan castle? I usually have 8 wizards but if they get knocked out then the rest of the army is doomed.

In war, there's almost always going to be flying troops in defending clan castle. How do you take care of them with GoVaHo?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this.

If you have somehow lured out the cc troops to a corner in the beginning:

- You can use a golem as a meat-sheild. When the cc troops are attacking the golem, you can deploy wizards to attack the cc troop, poison if you are carrying any. If the troops are not killed yet, only and only if needed, use rage on wizards or healing on golems.
- Another way would be to involve the queen as well along with the wizards in the above method.
- You can also use a number of barbarians instead of the golem to distract the cc troops.
- You can take a dragon in your army or your cc to kill the cc troops along with a poison. This would again include using a golem as a meat sheild and then deploying the dragon to kill the cc troops. Use queen or wizards if needed.

If you haven't lured out the cc troops in the beginning:

- You would know the position of clan castle and can predict slightly at what point of time and position would the cc troops come out. You can deploy wizards and queen accordingly to target the cc troops. You can drop poison on the cc troops and/or rage on the wizards and queen.
- You can also use dragon in a similar way mentioned above along with the queen to kill the cc troops.

When not luring out the cc troops in the beginning, you have to try your best that your wizards or dragon or queen are not vulnerable to the defenses during the attack and your other GoVaHo troops are taking the hits.

You can use some other troop as well instead of dragon and wizard, for example a baby dragon or any other troop that attacks defending air troops.

Comment: "I am assuming you have lured out the cc troops to a corner." At TH10 (and even TH9), this is not a guarantee. In fact, I'd use the assumption that it not be possible to lure the CC troops in most cases as good war bases will have high-level defenses and a layout specifically designed to prevent CC troop luring. If your strategies rely on the assumption that you can lure the CC troops out as opposed to dealing with them inside of the base, then this is probably an incomplete answer that can only apply to poorly designed war bases.

Comment: Yeah that's true, thanks @Ellesedil, I'll update the answer.